# OSM how to get the nearest node

Tags: javascript, path, gps, openstreetmap, nearest-neighbor

I transform the main data from OSM to tables ，and this is the main data from my osm
Below are my datas from database
There are also another data for gps data of bus，I collect the bus data every 20 seconds，now it is saved in my database.
And the question is what I should do to draw the path in osm using js or php.
I have designed the arithmetic but is does not workd，because it takes long time.

what I should do is correcting the route by osm data from my database table way and table node。

my 3 tables
[node from osm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyt0Y.png)

[way from osm][2]

[gps lat lon every 20 secons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tlNR.png)

Very appreciate you can help me

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

```
$mysql_server_name='localhost'; //改成自己的mysql数据库服务器
$mysql_username='root'; //改成自己的mysql数据库用户名
$mysql_password=''; //改成自己的mysql数据库密码
$mysql_database='goxml'; //改成自己的mysql数据库名
$conn=mysql_connect($mysql_server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password) or die("error connecting") ; //连接数据库
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); //数据库输出编码 应该与你的数据库编码保持一致.南昌网站建设公司百恒网络PHP工程师建议用UTF-8 国际标准编码.
mysql_select_db($mysql_database); //打开数据库
$sql_getstop ="SELECT RouteId,NameZh,Latitude,Longitude,GoBack FROM getstop; "; //SQL语句
$result_getstop = mysql_query($sql_getstop,$conn); //查询
$arr_getstop=array(array());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_getstop))
{
//$arr[]=$row1['Latitude'];
$arr_getstop[]=$row1;

}

echo $arr_getstop[1]['Latitude'];
echo $arr_getstop[9]['Latitude'];
//////////
$arr_test2 ="SELECT RouteID,BusID,Goback,Longitude,Latitude FROM test2 where RouteID='1' ;"; //SQL语句
$result_test2 = mysql_query($arr_test2,$conn); //查询
$arr_test2=array(array());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_test2))
{
    //$arr[]=$row1['Latitude'];
    $arr_test2[]=$row2;

}
for($j=1;$j<count($arr_test2);$j++)
{
echo $arr_test2[$j]['Latitude'];
echo $arr_test2[$j]['Longitude'];
echo "<br/>";
}
/*
//////////////////////////////输出所有的node
$arr_node ="SELECT ID,Lat,Lon FROM node where Lat>25.0883588 and Lon>121.4257346 and Lat <25.1883598 and Lon>121.4257316 ;"; //SQL语句
$result_node = mysql_query($arr_node,$conn); //查询
$arr_node=array(array());
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_node))
{
    //$arr[]=$row1['Latitude'];
    $arr_node[]=$row3;

}
echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%";
for($j=1;$j<count($arr_node);$j++)
{
echo $arr_node[$j]['Lat'];
echo $arr_node[$j]['Lon'];
echo "<br/>";
} */
///////////////////////超级运算
    echo "result is +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
for($j=0;$j<count($arr_test2);$j++)
    {
    $node_Lon1=$arr_test2[$j]['Longitude']+0.000117;
    $node_Lon2=$arr_test2[$j]['Longitude']-0.000117;
    $node_Lat1=$arr_test2[$j]['Latitude']+0.000117;
    $node_Lat2=$arr_test2[$j]['Latitude']-0.000117;
    $arr_node ="SELECT ID,Lat,Lon FROM node where Lat<$node_Lat1 and Lat>$node_Lat2 and Lon <$node_Lon1 and Lon>$node_Lon2 ;";
    $result_node = mysql_query($arr_node,$conn); //查询
    $arr_node=array(array());
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_node))
    {
    //$arr[]=$row1['Latitude'];
    $arr_node[]=$row3;

    }
    for($m=1;$m<count($arr_node);$m++)
    {
        echo $arr_node[$m]['Lat'];
        echo $arr_node[$m]['Lon'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    }
```

?>`enter code here`

the code runs more than serveal hours and can not appear the result

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In the title you are asking about how to get the nearest node. In the question body you are asking about drawing paths. Can you give us a clear and precise question?

Comment: do you have skype ID or line ID？

Comment: if I know the real node ，I can draw the real path，because path consists of noeds，so the question is I know the bus data（lat,lon)，when I draw it into the path(it makes mistake),so I have to use osm(including nodes)to find the nearest node to correct my path

Comment: http://a4.qpic.cn/psb?/V12wXiOY3cvAkn/tgzbzIKtjZkAYjE6uQUQmmJ3l9zUu44o5ul1w2BWtRg!/c/dLe4Fm02BQAA&ek=1&kp=1&pt=0&bo=6APPAAAAAAAFBwA!&sce=0-12-12&rf=0-18            This is the path,but is is not located in the right route. I need to use osm to correct the route. and make it into the central point on the way

Comment: So you want to match points to a corresponding road. This is called *map matching*. There have already been various other questions about map matching with OSM.

Comment: I am sorry,  node owns more than 3000 thousands  datas,and bus gps also has 300 thousands  datas, if i use the regular arithmetic ,I can not get the final result, because PC has spent more than 24 hours to process it,but no result.        I am so sad.

Comment: I use index to cut off the times of computing but does not work

Comment: No idea what you are referring to with "regular arithmetic". But read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are tarlking about a *[Map Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching)* problem.

There are multiple solutions for OSM:

- [graphhopper/map-matching](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching)
- [TrackMatching](https://mapmatching.3scale.net/)

Also read the answers to related questions on gis.stackexchange.com:

- [Different approaches for map matching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas)
- [Algorithms for matching segments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/algorithms-for-matching-segments)